# Point2D to move player left and right

Tags: java, position

I am trying to make a game in which the player moves only left and right. I am using `point2D.double` to store the position of the player. I got the direction of the player by using the code:

```
private Point2D.Double position = new Point2D.Double(0.0, 0.0);
private Point2D.Double newPostion = new Point2D.Double(0.0, 0.0);
public double getD() {
    double xPoint = position.getX();
    double yPoint = position.getY();
    double newXpoint = newPosition.getX();
    double newYpoint = newPosition.getY();
    d = Math.atan2(newYpoint - yPoint, newXpoint - x); 
    return d;
}
```

I have to move the player left and right according to this direction. I can't figure out the algorithm to change the `newPosition` according to player's selection.

Comment: Minor grammar fixes.

Comment: Algorithm is not what you're missing. You're missing code for listening to key events. You're using Swing, right?